# Design program to avoid a large if-else block

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have a large list of masks and codes

```
var codes = [
  foo: { mask: 0x1234, code: 0x0010 },
  bar: { mask: 0x1F00, code: 0x0310 },
  bla: { mask: 0x12F0, code: 0x2010 }
  ...
]
```

And I want to perform some operations...

```
var doStuff = function(number) {

  if ((number & codes.foo.mask) == codes.foo.code) {
    // do some stuff

  } else if ((number & codes.bar.mask) == codes.bar.code) {
    // do other stuff

  } else if ((number & codes.bla.mask) == codes.bla.code) {
    // do other stuff
  }
  ...

}
```

How would you design your program to avoid the large if-else block?
The sample code is in javascript but a design pattern in any language is ok for me.

Comment: Can you give a quick summary of what's in the "do other stuff" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `//do some stuff` parts into the foo, bar, bla objects, and then just loop over the array  i.e.

```
var codes = {
   foo: { mask: 0x1234, code: 0x0010, action: function(){/*do foo stuff*/} },
   bar: { mask: 0x1F00, code: 0x0310, action: function(){/*do bar stuff*/} },
   bla: { mask: 0x12F0, code: 0x2010, action: function(){/*do bla stuff*/} }
   ...
}

for (var item in codes){
  if ((number & codes[item].mask) == codes[item].code)
     codes[item].action();
}
```

You can also create a separate associative array just for the function, if you do not want to mix the data with the code (i.e. if the codes are fetched from a server)

```
var codes = {
   foo: { mask: 0x1234, code: 0x0010},
   bar: { mask: 0x1F00, code: 0x0310},
   bla: { mask: 0x12F0, code: 0x2010}
   ...
}

var funcs = {
   foo : function {/* do foo stuff */ },
   bar : function {/* do bar stuff */ },
   bla : function {/* do bla stuff */ },
}

for (var item in codes){
  if ((number & codes[item].mask) == codes[item].code)
     funcs[item]();
}
```

Comment: This was my first approach, but I didn't want to mix the `codes` table with the functions.

Comment: @PedroL - Edited to address that.

Answer (score 0):

Can create a array with the name of the functions in each case where the code is the index and name the value.

```
array[code] = "function_name"
```

Then applied the mask and call the function:

```
call(array[number & codes.foo.mask])
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, I would use a [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.  People in your situation have long handled this exact issue with a factory and polymorphism, which was the basis for Strategy.